# Minimal Linux environment/system?

Tags: linux

What is the bare minimum computer (not talking about configuration) which can run Linux kernel? Colloquially, we say "you can run Linux on washing machine" - what would that washing machine have to boot kernel and execute bash commands? Of course, it would require CPU with supported architecture, RAM and what else?

Or lets reformulate the question - if I wanted to build the computer from scratch using some mainstream microcontroller, which components that computer must have? Think Raspberry Pi Zero but even less hardware - no network, USB or display output. Just a board with bootable kernel turning LED on.

Theoretically, of course. I'm not planning to build it, I'm just interested how bare-bones computer can be. I've read something on this topic but long time ago but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be based on actual problems that you face (as per  the help system)

Comment: Where should I post this kind of question?

Comment: Retrocomputing?

Comment: As you say, supported CPU,ram, some kind of storage for kernel and some kind of io  (gpio / serial?) so it can do something meaningful. That said, at that level you are probably better with a non-linux device

Answer (score 3):

You need a [supported architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures) (that goes a bit beyond the processor), memory, a way to receive input and a way to send output. Input and output could be very basic, like say a button and a light (and you'd do everything using morse code, for example). If you start this basic, you will have to code those drivers.

Current mainstream Linux kind of needs an [memory managment unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) (you might [try to build without it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190350/mmu-less-kernel) though) but there are variants that can do without MMU (μClinux - [code here](https://github.com/uclinux-dev/elf2flt), that might be a starting point). There is also a version for boards with very limited processors and and memory, like embedded systems ([elks](https://github.com/jbruchon/elks)).

Although not Linux, in the spirit of your question, you could also go the [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) way; these are the [hardware requirements](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=usersguide:hardwarerequirements).

Comment: Exactly this was the question. You need supported architecture with memory management unit, input/output and drivers for them and what else? Clock chip like RTC? Comparing Linux to RTOS, is anything missing on typical ARM based (STM32...) boards which would prevent you from running something like μClinux?